# Passing BitBucket server credentials when using Ansible get_url

Tags: ansible, credentials, bitbucket-server, geturl

I am trying to write an ansible script to download files ( shell scripts ) from local bitbucket server.

Currently the code is as below.  It asks for id and pw input and when I printed it, it prints a correct output.

But the get_url call returns an html page.  The Id / pw entered does have access to the BB repo in question.

Is below not the correct way to pass credentials to bitbucket repo?

```
---

- name: Deployment of infrastructure changes
  hosts: kafka_broker[0]
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') }}"

  vars_prompt:
    - name: bb_username
      prompt: "User name for Bitbucket"
      private: no

    - name: bb_password
      prompt: "Password for "
      private: yes


  tasks:

    - name: Download connector scripts
      get_url:
        url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/browse/scripts/{{ item }}"
        dest:  /var/scripts
        url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
        url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
      with_items:
        - script1.sh
        - script2.sh
        - script3.sh
      register: showdlstatus
      become: yes
      become_user: '{{ bb_username }}'
```

How should I modify the above script to download files from BitBucket>

Thank you

Comment: (at least) two things: 1. you have `with_items:` but no reference to `{{ item }}` in your `url:` so that's unlikely to do what you expect 2. you didn't say what it is doing instead, nor whether you are able to curl down those scripts using that URL syntax. No one can _guess_ what is wrong with your setup

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight when cleaning up the url for info for posting. The url used is `url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/browse/scripts/{{ item }}"`.   I am able to use curl to download the files from the same  repo.  The curl command format is `curl -k -L --verbose -X GET  --user "${USERID}:${PASSWORD}"  -o ${filename}  bb_url`    Start of the output file is - `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><title>Log in - Bitbucket</title><script>
window.WRM=window.WRM||{};`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, they're terrible for that. And yes, that's what I expected was going to happen (for both the ignored credentials and the html response); for _modern_ platforms, there is a dedicated URL scheme for the raw bytes of a specific sha (GH uses `/raw/the-branch/the/file/name` GL uses `/-/raw/the-branch/the/file/name`) and authentication is usually special needs, not HTTP Basic

Comment: I also tried using - _url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/scripts/{{ item }}"_ and changing items by adding ?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster to script names - like - _script1.sh?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster_    Got same result   -  How do I determine what the authentication needs to be?  In the cURL command - it is plaintext id password that I am asking for at runtime, similar to the ansible script

Comment: With different attempts and trial and errors - the last one I tried was _force_basic_auth: yes_  and it worked.  @mdaniel, if that is a right approach, I will add  that as an answer, so  someone running into the same situation can find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding *force_basic_auth: yes* to the script resolved the issue

tasks:

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/scripts/{{ item }}"
    dest:  /var/scripts
    url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
    url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
    **force_basic_auth: yes**
  with_items:
    - script1.sh
    - script2.sh
    - script3.sh
```