# Ansible - Read dict items from file and use with loop

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120849/passing-bitbucket-server-credentials-when-using-ansible-get-url) effort a little further and want to download multiple files from BitBucket having different parent directories.  So I am trying to use the below script.

I want to put the mappings in a separate file and read it into the script, so that at subsequent times, I can just update that file, without having to touch the script.

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/{{ item.filename }}?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
    url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
    force_basic_auth: yes
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'scriptnamesnpaths.txt').splitlines() }}"
  register: showdlstatus
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ bb_username }}'
- debug: var=showdlstatus
```

And my `scriptnamesnpaths.txt` looks like this

```
{filename: 'scripts/dir1/script1.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir1/"}
{filename: 'scripts/dir1/script2.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir1/"}
{filename: 'scripts/dir2/script3.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir2/"}
{filename: 'releases/file1.json',          dest: "/scripts/releases/"}
{filename: 'releases/file2.json',          dest: "/scripts/releases/"}
```

I basically want to download different scripts from different paths in bitbucket to different locations on the server.

The error I am getting with this construct is

```
 {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
 The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'filename'
```

Which part am I doing wrong or missing?  I also tried with
`loop: "{{ lookup('dict', 'scriptnamesnpaths.txt').splitlines() }}"`

But get error about dict definition.

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a `file` lookup, it might be easiest just to make a [group_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables) file so that Ansible reads it for you automatically.

That is, if you create a file `groups_vars/all.yml`  with this content:

```
connector_scripts:
  - {filename: 'scripts/dir1/script1.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir1/"}
  - {filename: 'scripts/dir1/script2.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir1/"}
  - {filename: 'scripts/dir2/script3.sh',      dest: "/scripts/dir2/"}
  - {filename: 'releases/file1.json',          dest: "/scripts/releases/"}
  - {filename: 'releases/file2.json',          dest: "/scripts/releases/"}
```

You could then write your task like this:

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/{{ item.filename }}?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
    url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
    force_basic_auth: yes
  loop: "{{ connector_scripts }}"
  register: showdlstatus
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ bb_username }}'
```

---

If you really want to use a `file` lookup, you'll need to deal with the fact that for each iteration of your `loop`, the variable `item` is a *string*. You can't ask for something like `item.filename` because a string doesn't have an attribute `filename` (which is the source of the error you're seeing).  You would need to de-serialize each line before using it, for example:

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/{{ (item|from_yaml).filename }}?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster"
    dest: "{{ (item|from_yaml).dest }}"
    url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
    url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
    force_basic_auth: yes
  loop: "{{ connector_scripts }}"
  register: showdlstatus
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ bb_username }}'
```

You could simplify that a bit by moving the `from_yaml` call to a `vars` section so you only have to do it once:

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://bbserver:7990/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/raw/{{ item_converted.filename }}?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster"
    dest: "{{ item_converted.dest }}"
    url_username: '{{ bb_username }}'
    url_password: '{{ bb_password }}'
    force_basic_auth: yes
  vars:
    item_converted: "{{ item|from_yaml }}"
  loop: "{{ connector_scripts }}"
  register: showdlstatus
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ bb_username }}'
```

...but I think it's much easier to simply use the first solution and drop a file into `group_vars`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason for favoring putting the filenames/destinations in a script rather than the task? This would be a simplified version of the task with vars included in it:

```
- name: Download connector scripts
  get_url:
    url: "http://example.com/{{ item.key }}"
    dest: "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ files | dict2items }}"
  vars:
    files:
      filename1: "/path/to/dest/dir/"
      filename2: "/path/to/dest/dir/"
```

Comment: Since the script will be used by many people, I am worried about user error and script getting corrupted by typos and such when any team member wants to change the list of files and directories